# Digits In ICSharpCode.TextEditor.TextEditorControl Appear Black (And My Background Is Black)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm working on a .FF editor for PS3 MW2 patch_mp.ff's, My design is entirely dark themed, and everything works fine but one thing; numbers appear black on black background within an ICSharpCode.TextEditor.TextEditorControl, I've never seen one post of anyone else with this problem online, so have no way to find a method to troubleshoot it.

What I have tried:

Syntax Highlighting Strategy Methods
External Syntax Highlighing Via XSHD file
Setting All SystemColors used to Color.White
And So on..

Here is how I am creating my TextEditorControl:

```
        private TextEditorControl AddNewTextEditor(string title)
        {
            tab = new TabPage(title);
            tab.ForeColor = Color.White;
            TextEditorControl textEditorControl = new TextEditorControl();
            textEditorControl.ForeColor = Color.White;
            textEditorControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            textEditorControl.IsReadOnly = false;
            textEditorControl.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip2;
            textEditorControl.Text = readgsc;
            TextEditorControl Editor = textEditorControl;
            Font font = new Font("Consolas", 9f);
            if (font.Name == "Consolas")
                Editor.Font = font;
            Editor.ForeColor = Color.White;
            Editor.SetHighlighting("GSC");
            Editor.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            Editor.EnableFolding = true;
            Editor.ShowVRuler = false;
            Editor.Document.FormattingStrategy = new FormattingStrategy();
            Editor.Document.FoldingManager.FoldingStrategy = new MyFolding();
            Editor.IndentStyle = IndentStyle.Smart;
            Editor.Document.DocumentChanged += (sender, e) => SetModifiedFlag(Editor, true);
            Editor.TextChanged += new EventHandler(FileHasBeenEdited);

            //BackColor Is Color.Black\\
            HighlightColor highlightColor = new HighlightColor(Color.White, BackColor, false, false);

            DefaultHighlightingStrategy highlightingStrategy = Editor.Document.HighlightingStrategy as DefaultHighlightingStrategy;
            highlightingStrategy.SetColorFor("Default", highlightColor);
            highlightingStrategy.SetColorFor("LineNumbers", highlightColor);
            highlightingStrategy.SetColorFor("FoldLine", highlightColor);
            highlightingStrategy.SetColorFor("Digits", highlightColor);

            tab.Enter += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                TabPage tabPage = (TabPage)sender;
                //tabPage.BeginInvoke(new Action<TabPage>(delegate (TabPage p) {p.Controls[0].Focus();}), new object[]
                //{
                //    tabPage
                //});
            };
            tab.Controls.Add(Editor);
            //fileTabs is a TabControl With No Tabs Until Added Programatticaly\\
            fileTabs.Controls.Add(tab);
            fileTabs.SelectedTab = tab;
            if (_editorSettings == null)
            {
                _editorSettings = Editor.TextEditorProperties;
                OnSettingsChanged();
            }
            else
                Editor.TextEditorProperties = _editorSettings;
            return Editor;
        }
```

What I need as a result:

Numbers I can read on a black theme.

PLEASE NOTE: This issue is due to the system setting the color, this issue only happens on OS' before Windows 10. (Ones that set 90% of text to black)

If there is a way to change SystemColors.ControlText to another color forcefully, that would likely work.

Screenshot Of The Issue: [image: Black Numbers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Adding:
`<Digits name = "Digits" bold = "false" italic = "false" color = "White"/>`
to my syntax highlighting file, combined with my highlightingstrategy, then setting anything you want white to:
`Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);`
That should override any system colors.

Also keep in mind, the order you define your highlighting xshd file and my highlightingstrategy matters. The file itself and the "SetHighlighting" method must be done first, then the highlighting strategy.

If anyone else with this issue needs help, hmu on Discord via http://discord.me/Poppy